# Trying to retrieve the first longest word from a string, where a sentence contains strings of the same length ?

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, split

```
public class Challenge{                                             
public static String longestWord(String sentence){                                              
    String s= sentence;                                             
    String[] word=s.split(" ");                                             
    String four=" ";                                                
    for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++){                                             
      if(word[i].length()>=four.length()){                                              
        four=word[i];                                               
      }                                             
    }                                               
  return four;                                              
}
```

What i'm struggling with here is that if i have the sentence "This has lots that are four long" for example, the code defaults to printing "four" instead of "this" which i need -  im not sure how to implement the code which allows me to return the first longest string from a given sentence. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: Your code prints `long` and not `four`, FYI..

Comment: @NicholasK yeah sorry confusing variable names i know :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to stop overwriting your stored “longest word” when the length is equal to the current word. Replacing `>=` with `>` in your `if` statement should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable names are confusing, and redundant. I would assume the longest word is the first, and then begin the loop at the second word. And you want `>` (not `>=`). Like,

```
public static String longestWord(String sentence) {
    String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+");
    String longest = words[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length() > longest.length()) {
            longest = words[i];
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
```

**or** in Java 8+

```
public static String longestWord(String sentence) {
    return Stream.of(sentence.split("\\s+")).max(
            (a, b) -> Integer.compare(a.length(), b.length())).get();
}
```

Comment: IMHO, regex should include interpunctions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in Java 8:

```
public static String longestString(String sentence){
    return Stream.of(sentence.split("\\s+"))
            .max(Comparator.comparing(String::length))
            .orElse("");
}
```